# A compact convex subset is a strong deformation retract

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, retraction

Show that every compact convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is strong deformation retract.

I don't really know how to approach to this. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean a strong deformation retract of $\Bbb R^n$.
Suppose first $A$ is compact convex with an interior point $x_0$.
If $v$ is a unit vector, let $\lambda>0$ be the largest number
with $x_0+\lambda v\in A$. Define a homotopy on the ray
$\{x_0+sv:s\ge0\}$ by $(x_0+sv,t)\mapsto x_0+sv$ when $s\le \lambda$
and $(x_0+sv,t)\mapsto x_0+[(1-t)(s-\lambda)+t\lambda]v$ otherwise.
These fit together to give a suitable homotopy; this requires continuity
of the Minkowksi functional.

In general $A$ won't have an interior point, but it will lie in
an affine subspace in which it has. So first deformation-retract
$\Bbb R^n$ to this subspace, then use the above.