A convex, compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a deformation retract of $\mathbb{R}^n$
I want to prove that every convex, compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a deformation retract of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I have seen two other answers on this site: one is too complex for me and I'm finding problems with the other one.
First I've tried picturing the problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$. A compact, i.e, bounded and closed, and convex, can have an interior or not. However it should not have "rough" edges, in the sense that in the border you can't have discontinuities or something strange going on.
Thus it makes sense to fix a point of your set and from this point try to reescalate every other point.
That is, given $x_0 \in A$ (the set), then let $v$ be any vector with $||v||=1$. Then let it be $\gamma_v$ the largest real number (which it exists because it's bounded) such that $x_0+\gamma_v v \in A$. Note that every point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be expressed in this form, so we will define a function with $p=x_0+s v$, where $v$ is any unitary vector.
Then, define $r(p,t) = \begin{cases} 
x_0+sv & \text{if } s \leq \gamma_v \\
x_0+[(1-t)s+t\gamma_v]v & \text{if } s > \gamma_v 
\end{cases}$
which indeed, if I'm not mistaken, takes the given point and moves it along the line fixed by the vector in order to arrive at the border of the given set.
Now, where I'm stuck is to justify how this is continuous. Because it is a convex set and the border should be well-behaved, this should work but I don't know how to work the continuity with the arbritary vector.
Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Please reread your expression for $r$ again and fix all the typos (What's $s$? What's $\gamma$?) Also you would help all of us if you actually linked to the answers you found.

I edited the question to clear up the notation sorry. The post I'm refering to is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319310/a-compact-convex-subset-is-a-strong-deformation-retract

Do you mean deformation retract or strong deformation retract?

Deformation retract is enough, although I'm aware (or that I think) that is a strong deformation retract

Yes, it is a SDR.

Consider $A$ to be a solid square in $\Bbb R^2$, and $x_0$ is the midpoint of one of the sides. For points in the halfplane of that side containing the square, your function will retract all points outside the square to the intersection of the line connecting them to $x_0$ with the boundary of the square. But points in the other half-plane are all retracted directly to $x_0$ itself (as $\gamma_v = 0$ in those directions). Thus your retraction is discontinuous along the line of the side it is on. For this fuction to work, $x_0$ cannot be on a linear boundary segment.

Indeed that is true. Then if A has a non empty interior let the point be in there. For the other cases, it will be something similar to a bounded line, plane, hiperplane etc. Maybe in those cases it would be enough to, for example in the case of a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the plane from infinity to -infinity and from and to the extreme points get deformed in the usual way in a straigth line, and then the rest of $\mathbb{R}^2$ gets squished into the two extreme points.

"I have seen two other answers on this site: one is too complex for me and I'm finding problems with the other one." You should give references to these questions and answers and explain what problems you have.
